# Which one is more damaging? overvoltage or undervoltage?

Tags: voltage, power, current, design, damage

It is not easy to get the exact supply voltage required by loads. The supply is usually either a little bit higher or lower than desired.

It is known that both over & under voltage can potentially damage the device. I was working on supplying 120 V 15 LED fixtures. I had the voltage drop calculations and here I was thinking what if for any reason the voltage drops below 120, or if the voltage gets higher than 120 V, then I thought that the design should be based on avoiding the worst case scenario. If one of them was the worst, then I should add/subtract marginally in the calculations.

So, which one can be more damaging than the other? overvoltage or undervoltage?

Note that the question is applicable to be general although my intention is to ask on long-term design need basis but not on what could happen outside the circuit on short-term (for example, spikes or transients in voltage supply).

Comment: Bear in mind that 120v mains often spikes to 1500v, and often suffers brownouts and blackouts. Would that help you rephrase your question?

Comment: Note that switching a device on and off causes undervoltage for at least a short time.  In any case, I already go into this in the question this is a duplicate of.  See the first section of my answer.

Comment: @Olin Lathrop I saw your answer, but you did not state which one is more damaging. I can conclude which one, however, by reading your answer, but not decisively.

Comment: @Neil_UK I was asking the question specifically to see what to choose  higher/lower voltage supply regardless of what could happen outside the system.

Comment: @Olin Lathrop I think the question is useless. Many devices nowadays have 5-10% voltage tolerance. I just realized that after I read Olin Lathrop's asnwer.

Comment: I hate questions that imply that there is a simple answer. What is more dangerous, driving too hard, or driving too slow?

Comment: @ Wouter van Ooijen your analogy made it worse. I was just asking about which one is better, to have more potential or more current.